# How can I iterate over a result set and execute each statement? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

Here's my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') AS mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

I want to change the charset and collation from each varchar and table from the whole database, but the result set from this is just huge. How can I iterate over this query and execute each result in the SQL Language?

Comment: Write a stored procedure and execute the statements as prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this I would save the output of this `SELECT` statement to a file with the filetype `.sql`.

Then I would edit the `.sql` file with a text editor to make sure it contains what I hoped for.

Then I would use a MySQL client program to run the SQL file.

**Note well** The SQL data definition language commands written by your query won't work. Your query writes a command for every table in the system. You probably want to do this for the tables in one database.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',
              TABLE_SCHEMA,
              '``',
              TABLE_NAME,
              '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') 
                     AS mySQL
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA', 'MYSQL')
```

This query qualifies the table names with the data base name. It also chooses only the tables in the current database. Finally, it excludes the three system databases, because it's a really bad idea to try to alter tables in those databases.